# iOS standard menu inside a Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

A lot of iOS native apps have a menu like in this video (maybe this menu is standard and it has a name, but I don't know what is its name):
https://www.informatica-libera.net/videoLavoro/menuIOS.mp4

How can I do it with Codename One, of course in a portable way? It could be nicer if it can have the same opening and disposing animation effects like in the video.

Comment: I answered this a while back here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858529/how-to-code-an-iphone-style-popup-menu-in-cn1